# How can I request "High Accuracy" Location with the new SettingsApi on GooglePlayServices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm trying to use the new SettingsApi (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html) from GooglePlayServices to detect the need for changes on users settings without exiting the app.

My problem is that the dialog appears, but it only says it will require the Wifi and internet to access location. I also want it to request the GPS (this, is the High Accuracy mode or the device only mode).

My code for getting the LocationSettingsRequest:

```
public static LocationSettingsRequest getHighPriorityLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_ACTIVE);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        return new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                .setAlwaysShow(true)
                .build();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: what are the values of `FASTEST_INTERVAL` and `UPDATE_INTERVAL_ACTIVE`?

Comment: Do you already have GPS on for that device or is it also disabled?

Comment: Do you request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your Manifest?

Comment: I have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in the manifest @cigery

Comment: FASTEST_INTERVAL is 500, and UPDATE_INTERVAL_ACTIVE is 1500. @SamDozor

Comment: Either ways the result is the same. @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog only lists the **changes** needed to put your location settings to a more optimized states. Thus it won't ask you for GPS when:

- GPS is not available on your device, or
- GPS is already on.

By the way, neither `FASTEST_INTERVAL` nor `UPDATE_INTERVAL_ACTIVE` has any effect on that dialog.