# Enabling "High Accuracy" Location using Settings API in Google Play Service

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-location-services

I'm trying to enable the location from application using `Settings API`. In location dialog it shows message **`Use WiFi and cellular networks for location`**. On selection of `Yes` it is enabling the location but not the `GPS`.

[image: This is what I get]

But while I was playing with `Google Maps` in same device, it displays the message 
**`Use GPS, WiFi and cellular networks for location`** as like below screenshot.

[image]

And this is enabling the `GPS` also. How can I achieve the same as `Google Maps`.

Before posting here I hope I have checked all the possible options. Find my tryouts list below.

I have set the `priority` as `HIGH_ACCURACY` and min interval to 5 seconds

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

// Set the priority of the request
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

// Set the update interval to 10 seconds
locationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 10);

// Set the fastest update interval to 5 seconds
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 5);
```

Using only `FINE_LOCATION` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also referred few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755109/how-can-i-request-high-accuracy-location-with-the-new-settingsapi-on-googlepla) but nothing gave exact solutions. All I need is I would like to enable the location with `HIGH_ACCURACY` by default which enables the `GPS` Any help on this?

Comment: That is strange, it seems as though it should work as-is.  Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816683/4409409

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but after clicking the YES button to permit use GPS, the activity stops and runs the method onPause and then the activity begins in the method onResume.
So my solution was start again the localizacion in onResume method

```
@Override onResume public void () {

         //your code
         LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create ();

         // Set the priority of the request
         locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

         // Set the update interval to 10 seconds
         locationRequest.setInterval (1000 * 10);

         // Set the fastest update interval to 5 seconds
         locationRequest.setFastestInterval (1000 * 5);
         .....
         //start again the localizacion 
         LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, locRequest, this);
```